# Visiting Israel: A Mitzvah?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, travel, mitzvah, yerushalayim-jerusalem

Is visiting Israel a Mitzvah? (visiting as opposed to living)

Just some points I would hope an answer to cover:

- Was it a mitzvah back then?
- Is it still a mitzvah nowadays?
- Does the mitzvah apply throughout the year, or only during שלש רגלים?
- Is the mitzvah specifically for visiting Yerushalayim, or does anywhere in Israel suffice?

Comment: By _mitzva_ do you mean one of the 613 (plus _d'rabanan_ ones), or do you mean a _kiyum_ (or _chiyuv_) of _halacha_?

Comment: @msh210 What's the difference between the two? I probably mean the former.

Comment: well, revering one's parents is one of the 613 _mitzvos_. Not sitting in one's father's seat is a _chiyuv_ of _halacha_ (which happens to be an element of revering one's parents, but that's neither here nor there). Are you asking whether the _mone hamitzvos_ (those who list _mitzvos_) count visiting Israel as one of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no specific Mitzva to visit Eretz Yisroel, however (Kesubos 111a) walking 4 (Amos) cubits in Eretz Yisroel is a Mitzva. In addition there are many Mitzvos that can be done exclusively in eretz Yisroel.

Comment: "There is no specific Mitzva to visit Eretz Yisroel, however (Kesubos 111a) walking 4 (Amos) cubits in Eretz Yisroel is a Mitzva."  Hiyyuv or Kiyyum?

Comment: The Gemara you quote seems to contradict your first statement, that "there is no specific Mitzva to visit Eretz Yisroel".

Answer (score 3):

There is a mitzvah to live in Israel. The Ramban states that this is 1 of the 613 mitzvos of the Torah. Other rishonim consider it as a mitzvah also, but perhaps not 1 of the 613. It applies nowadays according to almost every view.

Visiting any place in Israel can be considered a partial fulfillment of that mitzvah. There is an additional mitzvah to visit the Beis haMikdash during the 3 regalim, but this would not apply nowadays.

Comment: Do you have sources to support your second paragraph?  I believe there are those who hold that a)the Mitzvah is to visit Yerushalayim, not just the Beith HaMikdash and/or b)it applies even though there is no Beith HaMikdash, just that c)some hold there is a Petur (exemption) all the while the Beith HaMikdash is not extant.

Comment: I know there are some famous Rabbanim (though who escapes me at the moment) who specifically travel to Yerushalayim for the Regalim to fulfill 'Aliyah LeRegel (pilgrimage requirement), as well as those who specifically DON'T travel to Yerushalayim for the Regalim, to avoid the prohibition of "Lo YeRaeh ... Reikam" (do not come empty-handed, ie., without the Ḥagigah (Festival) offering one is required to bring in the Beith HaMikdash).