# What is the purpose of "shlichut" money?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, shlichus-agency, kotel-western-wall

Whenever I have gone to Israel, people have given me "shlichut / mitzvah" money to donate at the Kotel.

Usually, I get to the Kotel, but, I don't always have time to do this, if I'm on a very short trip.

Some questions about this practice:

- What's the origin of this minhag?
- What's its purpose? Is the possession of this money supposed to act as a sort of "protection" that you will arrive in Israel safely?
- I gather that the giver makes you a *shaliach* and he specifically requests that you give it to someone at the *kotel*. Does this mean that I fyou donate it to someone else outside the kotel, you haven't fulfilled the giver's command? So, what should you do? Donate it, elsewhere, or return the money back to the giver?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1503836/jewish/Passing-the-Buck.htm https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/592448/jewish/Why-Do-Some-Give-a-Coin-to-a-Traveler.htm related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17227/why-do-we-give-tzedakah-money-to-someone-to-pass-along-in-israel

Comment: Because some of this question was answered in the related question, you might want to break this up and ask the separate "what if I don't go where they send me" as its own Q.

Comment: @rosends that last link looks like a duplicate to me (with the exception of the third question, which is an unrelated question about Shlichus in general).